# No se puede crear un nuevo hilo (Can't create a new thread) Error 1135, MySQL, en conexión persistente

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, vb6

Resulta que estamos implementando un nuevo esquema de sincronización de datos en el cual cada sucursal transmite las novedades haciendo INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

El asunto es que cuando eran pocas sucursales, no hay problema, pero hoy entre todas las sucursales y posiciones de trabajo, suman mas de 200 y el server tira el error mencionado en el titulo.

¿Que es lo que se puede hacer para sortear este problema?

El server es un windows Server 2008, 8GB, y normalmente esta en un 10% de uso de CPU y 15% de memoria.

El sistema que transimite esta desarrollado en VB6 y hace una conexión persistente.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado los límites de conexiones del servidor Mysql? Ya que la cantidad de clientes que mencionas han aumentado tanto, es lógico que la cantidad de conexiones también. Por otra parte ¿has implementado a conciencia la modalidad persistente de la conexión de tu sistema? Me refiero, a saber bien cuántas conexiones se realizarán, para poder aprovechar los recursos de la mejor manera, etc.

Comment: @quinqui Gracias, si aumente el limite de conexiones, de hecho al principio tenia error de 'too many connections' el cual arregle aumentando el limite de conexiones. Por otro lado no entiendo bien que queres decir con la utilización a conciencia de las conexiones persistentes, por cada posición de trabajo es 1 conexión.

Comment: La verdad, nunca uso conexiones persistentes, ya que programo en PHP y allí recomendaban evitarlas... Pero leyendo ahora la documentación, en verdad se hace énfasis en el uso inteligente de esta modalidad, en el sentido de tener claro de antemano cuántas conexiones se generarán, a fin de que configures tu sistema para que maneje esa cantidad y no otra. Algo así como que si te sales de esa cantidad, el sistema cae. Al menos así lo entendí yo ([de lo que leí aquí](https://forobeta.com/hospedaje-web/303263-conexiones-persistentes-mysql-que-que-son.html)), corríjanme los más entendidos, por favor.

Comment: Claro, como te comento, 1 usuario = 1 conexión, cada usuario se da de alta con nosotros primero con lo cual sabemos el potencial máximo de usuarios a atender.

Comment: Uhm, de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html): _**Error: 1135 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD):** Message: Can't create a new thread (errno %d); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug_, te tocaría revisar el sistema operativo, como sugieren si no es problema de memoria: ¿virus? ¿firewalls?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a @Quinqui por la ayuda, como mencionas en tu ultimo comentario, paracia ser un problema de sistema operativo, y buscando en internet decian que lo arreglaban aumentando el limite de threads para no super usuarios, pero esto solo en Linux. Windows no tiene este problema, asi que supuse que el error debia estar en MySQL:

resulta que hay un parametro que se llama open-files-limit

en **my.ini** debemos agregar la linea:

```
[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit=10240
```

Con lo cual aumenta el limit de archivos abiertos y deja de tirar el error.

Sigo probando que no de error, pero ya pase por mucho la cantidad de usuarios simultáneos conectado y no me ha dado error.

Comment: Qué bueno! Sigue haciendo las pruebas y nos cuentas cómo te va, de pronto sí era la solución al problema ^_^